# Codeigniter-- Foreach insert array to DB

Tags: php, sql, arrays, sql-server, codeigniter

So i want to achieve this in my table when I insert records.

```
**section       test        sample      quantity    specification**
 molecular    necropsy     Liver            3            n/a
 molecular    necropsy    Trachea           4            n/a
molecular     necropsy    Kidney            5           n/a
```

Note:

1. I have only 1 dropdown for the SECTION and 1 for the TEST.
2. On those 2 dropdown, I can have many SAMPLES, QUANTITY and SPECIFICATION.

   ```
   //This my CONTROLLER
   public function save_section_test1() {
   $section_id = $this->input->post('section');
   $test = $this->input->post('test');
   $samp = $this->input->post('samp');
   $quantity = $this->input->post('quantity');
   $specify = $this->input->post('specify');

   $save_sect = array();

   for ($i = 0; $i < count($sample); $i++) {

       $save_sect[] = array(
       'section_id' => $section_id[$i],
       'test_id' => $test[$i],
       'samp_id' => $sample[$i],
       'quantity' => $quantity[$i],
       'specification' => $specify[$i]
       );
   }

   $this->user_model->save_sect1($save_sect);
   redirect(base_url('user/show'));
   }

   //This is my MODEL
   public function save_sect1($save_sect) {
   return $this->db->insert_batch('tblsavesection', $save_sect); 
   }
   ```

Can someone please help me.Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: i didn't understand you note can you explain in brief,

Comment: I only have 1 input for SECTION and 1 for TEST. But in SAMPLES, QUANTITY, and SPECIFICATION i have more than 1 input. What i want is to loop the SAMPLE, QUANTITY, AND SPECIFICATION to the SECTION and TEST. so that i can have the output just like above on above.

Comment: did you want to optimize or code , or you facing some error on it?

Comment: I am experiencing an error sir using my current code. Nothing is inserted to my db. And my webpage keeps showing "HTTP ERROR 500".

Comment: can you do one thing just share `echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST);die;` put before this line `$section_id = $this->input->post('section');`

Comment: The output sir is:
  Array
(
    [section_id] => 1
    [test_id] => 102
    [samp_id] => 10
    [quantity] => 3
    [specify] => hey
)

I inputed 3 samples, 3 quantities and 3 specification. but only 1 line is capture. it didn't loop

Comment: that's ok , first ill check in local then i'll answer your question

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Bless you

Comment: You can check my answer if you get error then let me know

Comment: I used your answer sir but I experienced an error. I comment below your answer the error I encountered.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, the count is performed on `$sample` , but that variable is undefined, so the your for loop should be like this :

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($samp); $i++) {
    $save_sect[] = array(
    'section_id' => $section_id[$i],
    'test_id' => $test[$i],
    'samp_id' => $samp[$i],
    'quantity' => $quantity[$i],
    'specification' => $specify[$i]
    );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

CONTROLLER

```
public function save_section_test1() {

    $post=$this->input->post();
    $result=$this->user_model->save_sect1($post);

    redirect(base_url('user/show'));
  }
```

Model

```
public function save_sect1($params) {
    $save_sect = array();
    foreach($params as $key=>$value){
      $save_sect[$key] = array(
          'section_id' => $value['section'],
          'test_id' => $value['test'],
          'samp_id' => $value['samp'],
          'quantity' => $value["quantity"],
          'specification' => $value['specify']
      );
    }

    $this->db->insert_batch('tblsavesection', $save_sect);
    return $this->db->trans_status();
  }
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Uninitialized string offset: 0

Filename: models/user_model.php

Line Number: 153 till 158

Comment: Please don't say `sir`  and can you share which line `error` occured.

Comment: and can you check you database whether i`its` inserted or not

Comment: 'emp_id' => $value['emp_id'],

                'section_id' => $value['section'],
                'test_id' => $value['drop_molec'],
                'samp_id' => $value['samp'],
                'quantity' => $value["quantity"],
                'specification' => $value['specify']

Comment: the lines below $save_sect[$key] = array(        at the model

Comment: Looking forward to that. Thank you so much

Comment: Do you mind if we talk even in google hangouts? My account here is not yet able to post Images. I would like to show my webpage and my database so that I can explain further the problem. my hangouts is jfdelcarmen@bountyfresh.com.ph

Comment: My codes is a little bit messy so I guess I can explain it to you if I just show the screenshot of my html. Thanks

Comment: i sent request you can check on hangout